# Виды QR кодов, и работа с ними на Android

Tags: android, qr

давно интересует тема с чтением и генерацией различных баркодов, в том числе QR, так как он самый популярный)
Сделал я простое приложение для себя, где сканирую и генерирую коды всех поддерживаемых типов, через уже существующие библиотеки, но вот при работе с этим всем обратил свой взор на разные возможности QR, таких как подключение WIFI через ряд параметров, добавление контактов (vCard, meCard), мероприятия, и наверное еще что-то.

Собственно вопрос, есть ли методы обработки всего этого добра, или нужно писать свои? Может есть спецификация разметки, вообщем где об этом можно внятно поузнавать?

Спасибо!

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/18198/qr-code-barcode-scanner-android

Comment: Andrew Goroshko -> поверхностно в самом посте ответа не нашел, но я так понимаю что нужно в коде представленной либы поколупать, спасибо!)